# What value (Cookie, SessionID, variable) best represents a WIF Session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, wif, windows-identity

I want to track a user's logon session from the time they login to my site, to the time they logoff.

Is there a pre-existing cookie I should use, or variable?  I thought of using ASP.NET sessionIDs but read on StackOverflow that these numbers may change.

I would save my own Session cookie, but I don't want to do something that could be done more efficiently another way.  I'm using Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) to handle my authentication layer.

The only cookie I see in fiddler is a FedAuth cookie so I assume that I might be able to derive some valuable information from it, but I don't know where / how in the WIF framework to gain access to such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIF gives a bunch of events you can subscribe to. See these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule_members.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.sessionauthenticationmodule_members.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can control some of the cookie characteristic via the config - [A Hidden Gem: The WIF Config Schema](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2010/05/11/a-hidden-gem-the-wif-config-schema.aspx). In particular, note the cookieHandler section and

> hideFromScript - Boolean - default true Controls whether the
>   "HttpOnly" flag is emitted for any cookies  written. Certain web
>   browsers honor this flag by keeping client-side script from accessing
>   the cookie value.

In terms of WIF, there is a Deserialize in Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenCookieSerializer and a CookieHandler (Delete / Read / Write) in IdentityModel.Web.